# Fetch all observations that contain a specimen resource?

Tags: hl7-fhir

I want to fetch Observations that contain a reference to a Specimen resource. More broadly , how to query any resource on the condition that it contains a reference to another specific resource ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Observation resource has a search parameter `specimen`, which you can use for your search if the server supports the `missing` modifier:

```
GET [base]/Observation?specimen:missing=false
```

In general: look for a search parameter for the field involved, and if present, use that in combination with the modifier.

Comment: Thank you so much ! I completely missed the missing modifier.